# Is there a way to auto reload/refresh flask webpages on a localhost after an event?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, server, refresh

There are multiple clients connected to the localhost server, when one enter some data in the input field, how do I get web pages on other client's devices to refresh?

Comment: You should use websockets.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of doing this, the most popular nowadays is WebSockets as @bülent-akgül mentioned.

Flask as a module of it called Flask-SocketIO. You can find the documentation in the following link https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Besides WebSockets, you can also use Ajax and Comet. https://www.infoq.com/news/2008/12/websockets-vs-comet-ajax/